# Google Maps iOS SDK, Getting Directions between 2 locations

Tags: ios, xcode, google-maps, cocoa-touch, google-maps-sdk-ios

While I am using Google Maps SDK, I am trying to get driving direction between two locations on iOS. I know we can do this using two methods:-

1.) Using URL Scheme, for which it is necessary that Google Maps App is installed on your     device.

2.) Using Directions API, via Request-Response and then parsing the JSON. Displaying markers to show the direction.

Now, my question is there any other way by which I can do this on iOS? I need to show the direction from my current location to a particular location of which i have the Lat/Long.

I mean is it really not possible to simply pass 2 location as parameter and Google Maps SDK, will give me the directions?

Thanks,

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It sounds like you are looking for UI Chrome like the Google Maps app has for showing directions. Google Maps SDK for iOS will paint you a map, but you are responsible for the additional navigation chrome.

You can use the [Google Directions API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/) to request directions, and then use the encoded path returned from the service to draw a [GMSPolyline](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/reference/interface_g_m_s_polyline) using [GMSPath's pathFromEncodedPath:](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/reference/interface_g_m_s_path#a4060269354374332afbb532557c4899e) method.

Comment: Adding to Brett's answer, take a look at the Google Dev Live presentation to do this. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AdV7bCWuDYg

Answer (score 47):

```
    NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                       @"%@?origin=%f,%f&destination=%f,%f&sensor=true&key=%@",
                       @"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json",
                       mapView.myLocation.coordinate.latitude,
                       mapView.myLocation.coordinate.longitude,
                       destLatitude,
                       destLongitude,
                       @"Your Google Api Key String"];
NSURL *directionsURL = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];


ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:directionsURL];
[request startSynchronous];
NSError *error = [request error];
if (!error) {
    NSString *response = [request responseString];
    NSLog(@"%@",response);
    NSDictionary *json =[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[request responseData] options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];
    GMSPath *path =[GMSPath pathFromEncodedPath:json[@"routes"][0][@"overview_polyline"][@"points"]];
    GMSPolyline *singleLine = [GMSPolyline polylineWithPath:path];
    singleLine.strokeWidth = 7;
    singleLine.strokeColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    singleLine.map = self.mapView;
}
else NSLog(@"%@",[request error]);
```

Note: make Sure Your Google Direction API Sdk Is Enable in Your google developer Console.

Comment: @muhammad Noman this api not working. it says implement on server side, because client side it's not safe with private key.

Comment: When you are using this for IOS app please make sure to make the Google API restriction to :None other wise it will restrict coz of your IP

Comment: ASIHTTPRequest is depreciated , you should use Alamofire or URLRequest

Answer (score 14):

These lines shows location between a given latitude / longitude and user location;

```
NSString *googleMapUrlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.google.com/?saddr=%f,%f&daddr=%@,%@", mapView.userLocation.coordinate.latitude, mapView.userLocation.coordinate.longitude, destinationLatitude, destinationLongtitude];

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:googleMapUrlString]];
```

Comment: Thanks you are right, but I got the answer, Actually Its not possible to display the direction within your app. Google Maps SDK iOS, can't display direction within the app.

Answer (score 9):

**Swift 3.0 & XCode 8.0**
Using AFNetworking & SwiftJson

```
        let destLatitude="26.9124"
        let destLongitude="75.7873"
        mapView.isMyLocationEnabled = true
        var urlString = "\("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json")?origin=\("28.7041"),\("77.1025")&destination=\(destLatitude),\(destLongitude)&sensor=true&key=\("Your-Api-key")"

        urlString = urlString.addingPercentEncoding( withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed)!

        let manager=AFHTTPRequestOperationManager()

        manager.responseSerializer = AFJSONResponseSerializer(readingOptions: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.allowFragments) as AFJSONResponseSerializer

        manager.requestSerializer = AFJSONRequestSerializer() as AFJSONRequestSerializer

        manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = NSSet(objects:"application/json", "text/html", "text/plain", "text/json", "text/javascript", "audio/wav") as Set<NSObject>


        manager.post(urlString, parameters: nil, constructingBodyWith: { (formdata:AFMultipartFormData!) -> Void in

            }, success: {  operation, response -> Void in
                //{"responseString" : "Success","result" : {"userId" : "4"},"errorCode" : 1}
                //if(response != nil){
                let parsedData = JSON(response)
                print_debug("parsedData : \(parsedData)")
               var path = GMSPath.init(fromEncodedPath: parsedData["routes"][0]["overview_polyline"]["points"].string!)
                 //GMSPath.fromEncodedPath(parsedData["routes"][0]["overview_polyline"]["points"].string!)
                var singleLine = GMSPolyline.init(path: path)
                singleLine.strokeWidth = 7
                singleLine.strokeColor = UIColor.green
                singleLine.map = self.mapView
                //let loginResponeObj=LoginRespone.init(fromJson: parsedData)


                //  }
            }, failure: {  operation, error -> Void in

                print_debug(error)
                let errorDict = NSMutableDictionary()
                errorDict.setObject(ErrorCodes.errorCodeFailed.rawValue, forKey: ServiceKeys.keyErrorCode.rawValue as NSCopying)
                errorDict.setObject(ErrorMessages.errorTryAgain.rawValue, forKey: ServiceKeys.keyErrorMessage.rawValue as NSCopying)

        })
```

Answer (score 9):

Swift 4.1, Xcode  9.4.1

```
//Here you need to set your origin and destination points and mode 
let url = NSURL(string: "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=Machilipatnam&destination=Vijayawada&mode=driving")

//OR if you want to use latitude and longitude for source and destination
//let url = NSURL(string: "\("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json")?origin=\("17.521100"),\("78.452854")&destination=\("15.1393932"),\("76.9214428")")

        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url! as URL) { (data, response, error) -> Void in

            do {
                if data != nil {
                    let dic = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableLeaves) as!  [String:AnyObject]
//                        print(dic)

                    let status = dic["status"] as! String
                    var routesArray:String!
                    if status == "OK" {
                        routesArray = (((dic["routes"]!as! [Any])[0] as! [String:Any])["overview_polyline"] as! [String:Any])["points"] as! String
//                            print("routesArray: \(String(describing: routesArray))")
                    }

                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        let path = GMSPath.init(fromEncodedPath: routesArray!)
                        let singleLine = GMSPolyline.init(path: path)
                        singleLine.strokeWidth = 6.0
                        singleLine.strokeColor = .blue
                        singleLine.map = mapView
                    }

                }
            } catch {
                print("Error")
            }
        }

        task.resume()
```

Here, you need to add your **key (google api key)** to the above API.

Comment: Thanks, the `GMSPath` part was very helpful – just a note though: I wouldn't recommend force unwrapping but rather defining a codable struct with as many fields as you need (maybe you also want to parse the steps of the routes?) and then let a `JSONDecoder` try to decode the object from the response for you. Especially easy when using Moya / Alamofire.

Answer (score 8):

I had done it as it also shows **PINS DISTANCE AND DURATION** on map with **DIRECTION ROUTE**. But dont forget to set your **GOOGLE DIRECTION API TO ENABLED** in your **GOOGLE DEVELOPER CONSOLE**

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
[manager.requestSerializer setCachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData];

NSString *urlString =@"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json";

 NSDictionary *dictParameters = @{@"origin" : [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",_sourceAdd], @"destination" : [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",_destinationAdd], @"mode" : @"driving", @"key":@"AIzaSyD9cWTQkAxemELVXTNUCALOmzlDv5b9Dhg"};

[manager GET:urlString parameters:dictParameters success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {


    GMSPath *path =[GMSPath pathFromEncodedPath:responseObject[@"routes"][0][@"overview_polyline"][@"points"]];
    NSDictionary *arr=responseObject[@"routes"][0][@"legs"];
    NSMutableArray *loc=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    loc=[[arr valueForKey:@"start_location"]valueForKey:@"lat"];
    _sourceloc.latitude=[loc[0] doubleValue];

    loc=[[arr valueForKey:@"start_location"]valueForKey:@"lng"];
    _sourceloc.longitude=[loc[0] doubleValue];

    loc=[[arr valueForKey:@"end_location"]valueForKey:@"lat"];
    _destinationloc.latitude=[loc[0] doubleValue];

    loc=[[arr valueForKey:@"end_location"]valueForKey:@"lng"];
    _destinationloc.longitude=[loc[0] doubleValue];


    NSString *dis,*dur;
    loc=[[arr valueForKey:@"distance"]valueForKey:@"text"];
    dis=loc[0];

    loc=[[arr valueForKey:@"duration"]valueForKey:@"text"];
    dur=loc[0];


    NSString *sa,*da;
    loc=[arr valueForKey:@"start_address"];
    sa=loc[0];

    loc=[arr valueForKey:@"end_address"];
    da=loc[0];

    UIAlertView *av=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Route Info" message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Distance:%@ \nDuration:%@",dis,dur] delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Okay" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [av show];



    GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:_sourceloc.latitude  longitude:_sourceloc.longitude zoom:10];
    mapView = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectZero camera:camera];

    GMSMarker *marker = [GMSMarker markerWithPosition:_sourceloc];
    marker.title=@"Source";
    marker.snippet =sa;
    marker.appearAnimation = kGMSMarkerAnimationPop;
    marker.map = mapView;


    GMSMarker *marker2 = [GMSMarker markerWithPosition:_destinationloc];
    marker2.title=@"Destination";
    marker2.snippet =da;
    marker2.appearAnimation = kGMSMarkerAnimationPop;
    marker2.map = mapView;

    GMSPolyline *singleLine = [GMSPolyline polylineWithPath:path];
    singleLine.strokeWidth = 4;
    singleLine.strokeColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    singleLine.map = mapView;

    self.view = mapView;



} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
```

Comment: just to clarify '_sourceAdd' and '_destinationAdd' params in @PatelJigar's solution can be the following formats: origin=24+Sussex+Drive+Ottawa+ON, origin=41.43206,-81.38992, origin=place_id:ChIJ3S-JXmauEmsRUcIaWtf4MzE     ref: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro#https-or-http

Answer (score 1):

Using **Swift** I definitely solved in this way.
My purpose was finding distance between two coordinates:

```
import AFNetworking 

/**
 Calculate distance between two valid coordinates

 - parameter origin:      origin coordinates
 - parameter destination: destination coordinates
 - parameter completion:  completion callback
 */
func calculateDistance(origin origin: CLLocation, destination: CLLocation, completion: (distance: Double?) -> Void) {

    let service = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json"
    let originLat = origin.coordinate.latitude
    let originLong = origin.coordinate.longitude
    let destLat = destination.coordinate.latitude
    let destLong = destination.coordinate.longitude
    let urlString = "\(service)?origin=\(originLat),\(originLong)&destination=\(destLat),\(destLong)&mode=driving&units=metric&sensor=true&key=<YOUR_KEY>"
    let directionsURL = NSURL(string: urlString)

    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: directionsURL!)

    request.HTTPMethod = "GET"
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
    let operation = AFHTTPRequestOperation(request: request)
    operation.responseSerializer = AFJSONResponseSerializer()

    operation.setCompletionBlockWithSuccess({ (operation: AFHTTPRequestOperation!, responseObject: AnyObject!) -> Void in

        if let result = responseObject as? NSDictionary {
            if let routes = result["routes"] as? [NSDictionary] {
                if let lines = routes[0]["overview_polyline"] as? NSDictionary {
                    if let points = lines["points"] as? String {
                        let path = GMSPath(fromEncodedPath: points)
                        let distance = GMSGeometryLength(path)
                        print("wow \(distance / 1000) KM")

                    }
                }
            }
        }
        }) { (operation: AFHTTPRequestOperation!, error: NSError!)  -> Void in
            print("\(error)")
    }

    operation.start()

}
```

Comment: This does not answer the question

Answer (score 1):

```
(void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:30.692408
                                                            longitude:76.767556
                                                                 zoom:14];
    GMSMapView *mapView = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectZero camera:camera];
    mapView.myLocationEnabled = YES;

    // Creates  markers in the center of the map.


    GMSMarker *marker = [[GMSMarker alloc] init];
    marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(30.6936659,  76.77201819999999);
    marker.title = @"Chandigarh 47c";
    marker.snippet = @"Hello World";
    marker.map = mapView;

    GMSMarker *marker1 = [[GMSMarker alloc] init];
    marker1.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(30.742138,  76.818756);
    marker1.title = @"Sukhna Lake";
    marker1.map = mapView;
    //creating a path

    GMSMutablePath *path = [GMSMutablePath path];
    [path addCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(@(30.6936659).doubleValue,@(76.77201819999999).doubleValue)];
    [path addCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(@(30.742138).doubleValue,@(76.818756).doubleValue)];

    GMSPolyline *rectangle = [GMSPolyline polylineWithPath:path];
    rectangle.strokeWidth = 2.f;
    rectangle.map = mapView;
    self.view=mapView;

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If someone is looking to parse the distance from routes array following is the way to get the distance in swift 4/5

```
let distance = responseJSON["routes"][0]["legs"][0]["distance"]["text"]
```

Answer (score 0):

As @iOS suggested I'm also posting my answer to show you a way how to accomplish it using Codable and Alamofire/Moya.

To do so, you'd have to remodel the GoogleMaps Response entities, like so:

```swift
/// Struct for modelling a response from the Google Maps Directions API. This is the "root level"
struct GMSDirectionsResponse: Codable {
    /// The suggested routes
    let routes: [GMSRoute]
    /// Status telling if request was okay
    let status: String
}
/// Struct for modelling a Route suggested by GoogleMaps Directions API.
struct GMSRoute: Codable {
    /// Represents an area in the map
    struct Bounds: Codable {
        // You can omit these structs for your case. 
        // Just to give an idea how it would look like if you model the entire response
        // ...
    }
    
    struct Leg: Codable {
        // ...
    }
    
    /// A single step of a route
    struct Step: Codable {
        // ...
    }
    
    /// Structure around the coded representation of the GMSPath
    struct OverviewPolyline: Codable {
        /// A coded representation of the GMSPath
        let points: String
    }
    
    /// The bounds to show on the map to include the whole route
    let bounds: Bounds?
    /// All legs of this route, including the single steps
    let legs: [Leg]?
    /// The path to walk/drive/etc. this route
    let overview_polyline: OverviewPolyline?
    /// A textual summary of the most important roads to take
    let summary: String?
}
```

You can see how a response object consists of an array of routes and a status string (e.g. `"OK"`). Each route has a few properties again, including the `overview_polyline` field. For being able to have that object decoded by a `JSONDecoder` you also need to model that class (it simply contains a string value for the key `points`.

Now if you only need the `overview_polyline` it's perfectly fine to omit all other unneeded properties and structs as long as you still model the hierarchical structure of the response (e.g. GMSDirectionsResponse > GMSRoute > OverviewPolyline > `points`).

What you can do now is to ask a `JSONDecoder` to decode a `GMSDirectionsResponse` from the body data with a single line! In my project I used [Moya](https://github.com/Moya/Moya) but I'm sure you can also do it with `URLSession`'s `data` object.

```swift
// let moya do request
let moya = MoyaProvider<YourGMSService>()
moya.request(.getDirections(origin: origin, destination: destination)) { (result) in
    switch result {
    case .success(let response):
        // check if request was successful
        if
            // makes sure status is code is 2xx
            (try? response.filterSuccessfulStatusCodes()) != nil,
            // this line tries to decode a GMSDirectionsResponse object from response.data
            let directions = try? JSONDecoder().decode(GMSDirectionsResponse.self, from: response.data)
        {
            // successful request, converted response to JSON Dictionary
            NSLog("GET DIRECTIONS: Success")
            
            // here we can check for the directions properites already!
            NSLog("GoogleMaps Directions request finished with status %@", directions.status)
            
            // check if we have at least one GMSRoute with an overview_polyline
            guard let encodedPath = directions.routes.first?.overview_polyline else { return }
            // now let's use the encoded path:
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                let path = GMSPath.init(fromEncodedPath: encodedPath.points)
                
                // continue as in other answers (Y)
                let singleLine = GMSPolyline.init(path: path)
                singleLine.strokeWidth = 6.0
                singleLine.strokeColor = .blue
                singleLine.map = mapView
            }
            return
        }
        // some error handling if we couldn't parse the data to a GMSDirectionsResponse object
        NSLog("Could not parse JSON from Directions API Response:\n%@", response.debugDescription)
    case .failure(let error):
        // we had an error
        NSLog(error.localizedDescription)
    }
    // log and complete with nil
    NSLog("GET DIRECTIONS: Failed")
}
```

This might look like a huge load of code but it's totally convenient and it keeps you from messing around with JSON subscript members and lots of `[]` braces.

If you have questions, I'm happy to help!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a restricted key, you have to add `X-Ios-Bundle-Identifier` header with the bundle you restricted the key to. With that header it works also from Postman.[image]

Answer (score -1):

Create a key in google developer console make sure your project is created with App bundleID after that add the following code

```
NSString *KEY=@"";
NSString *Origin=@"";
NSString *Destination=@"";
NSString *str_maps=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=%@&destination=%@&key=%@",Origin,Destination,KEY];
NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:str_maps];
 NSData *dta=[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
NSDictionary *dict=(NSDictionary *)[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:dta options:kNilOptions error:nil];
NSLog(@"%@",dict);
```