# Directions not following road on IOS map

Tags: ios, iphone, google-maps, mapkit

I am working on an app where I give direcctions in a country. Directions in that country is not available from apple so i decided to use google api on an apple map. However as you can see from my sceenshot. Although I find the location on my iphone mmap i just get straight lines versus following the route that google does.

Does this have anything to do with using google API on Apple Maps? I have no reason why this is happening.

[image]

this is the link I pass to the web from my app

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=15.299503,-61.387292&destination=Rosalie+Bay+Resort,+Rosalie,+Saint+David+Parish,+Dominica&sensor=true

Comment: How are you creating the Polylines to draw on the map?  If you are using the Google Maps API, I would recommend using Google Map views instead of Apple.

Comment: ok, going to....change over to the google map. however have you ever done directions from google maps ? did you get results like mine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using MKMapView, you should check out the following examples:
http://www.meonbinary.com/2014/02/route-directions-with-ios7-mapkit-and-google-maps-api
http://sugartin.info/2011/10/12/drawing-route-on-google-map-mkmapview/

If you are using GMSMapView, check out this stack question: [Drawing Route Between Two Places on GMSMapView in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22550849/drawing-route-between-two-places-on-gmsmapview-in-ios)

Comment: I have looked at the 1st link and actually followed it and i stll get thse weird lines

Comment: Are you using the Google Maps Javascript v3 API, Google maps SDK for iOS, or something else? Can you post your code?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread, but you are not getting 'weird' polylines..
You drawn them manually from the steps.
If you look closely on the right map, you see the 'white' dots ?
Your polylines follow these dots, you can name them the direction steps.

I have the same issue when I simulate the directions :) That's how I got here.
For just drawing, draw routeRequest.routes[0].polyline directly to the map, and it looks good :)