# iOS) Getting no route from two coordinates from google directions api

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, google-polyline, google-directions-api

I'm trying to get a route between the origin coordinate and the destination coordinate.

I referenced [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22550849/drawing-route-between-two-places-on-gmsmapview-in-ios).

So My code is below:

```
let url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=37.496375,126.9546903&destination=37.48121,126.9505233&mode=walking&key=MY_KEY"
Alamofire.request(url).responseJSON 
{ response in
print(response.request)  // original URL request
print(response.response) // HTTP URL response
print(response.data)     // server data
print(response.result)   // result of response serialization

let json = JSON(data: response.data!)
let routes = json["routes"].arrayValue

for route in routes
{
    let routeOverviewPolyline = route["overview_polyline"].dictionary
    let points = routeOverviewPolyline?["points"]?.stringValue
    let path = GMSPath.init(fromEncodedPath: points!)
    let polyline = GMSPolyline.init(path: path)
    polyline.map = self.mapView
 }
}
```

But as a result, response.data is below:

```
{
 "status" : "ZERO_RESULTS",
 "available_travel_modes" :
 [
 "TRANSIT"
  ],
 "geocoded_waypoints" : [
{},
{}],"routes" : []}
```

About this issue, I searched it and found that it may be caused when the coordinate can not be converted into the address.

But I did check both coordinates are converted into the right address by 'CLGeocoder'(reverseGeocodeLocation).

Finally, I did check at 'maps.google.com' that the same coordinates are addressed and the route is shown to me.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Do you get route with other origin, destination?

Comment: I tested different pair (new_origin,new_destination) , but the result is the same, i will update the exact url I requested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> available_travel_modes contains an array of available travel modes.
>   This field is returned when a request specifies a travel mode and gets
>   no results. The array contains the available travel modes in the
>   countries of the given set of waypoints.

Your response returned as

```
"available_travel_modes":["TRANSIT"]
```

So try changing `mode=walking` to `&mode=transit`

Comment: Thank you,  with the option 'transit', the poly line ignores the real walking road a little.

Comment: Can you attach a screenshot?

Comment: Yes, but I think because it reflects the route for bus... Hard to parse this complicated information.

Comment: There is no option to improve, I checked google maps for mobile and web and the result is the same

Answer (score 0):

change mode walking to driving, i mean google cant find way for walking, but i offer use martix api like this 
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?units=metric&origins=(currentLat),(currentLng)&destinations=(restLat),(restLng)&key=MY_KEY&mode=driving

Comment: Thankyou , but as you can see the answer above , only 'transit' option returns well