# GoogleMaps : How to draw dash line to connect with starting point of direction path on google map ios

Tags: ios, google-maps, swift3, google-directions-api

I am using google map in the my project for direction & show route. I had done all things but I am not able to draw the dash line to connect with starting point of route from my location or building.

**See my app screenshot screenshot 1**

**Now I want to draw dash line like google-maps screenshot 2**

[image]

Any advice and suggestions will be greatly appreciated

Comment: downvoters can you tell me suggestions please?

Comment: you have two locations - why not just draw a line between them?  Do you mean to have a curved path as shown?  If there's no route defined there, how do you come up with that line rather than a straight line between the two points?

Comment: Bro that is the my question i just want to connect to starting point of route from my location/building like google map.(If you are telling to draw line then i don't have starting point lat-long its just return polypoints to draw line like `"c}kpB{daaM_G\\kBNUD@Ns@r@kAlBw@tAKr@Cd@MX{A`C}BnD[d@LJaD`FS\\UV_@Ty@\\ADNz@HXZx@zBbETh@tAdD`AjAd@r@z@dC|A~Er@jCjB|FzArE`@|Af@jCt@xDfAhH^xCL|AFj@Tt@~EpKrAdDh@~Av@nCrAvFvApGp@rBx@`B^p@VXNR`@x@Xn@n@tBh@~AXp@Zl@z@rAFTFfABh@Hv@ThAp@lCr@~D`BnNZhDPlAr@hEB`@Bl@F~BD|FAnCB~CAdCEjCBrDDzANbAJt@Fj@CbAGlA?~ATvB@l@Gt@UjBMv@UhBAbAH`AHlBBdA?`@e@DgAHcIj@[@@RcEZ"`)

Comment: then convert your current location to another polypoint, and add a MKPolyLine to the map

Comment: its not possible at all to convert current location directly to polypoints :(

Comment: Please does anyone have idea to do it exact like googlemaps?

Comment: @yummy , hi, did you found the solution to show dotted arc line between starting point and marker as in 2nd screenshot?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For add dash line to connect with starting & end point you have to do little more stuffs in direction path json response, I have drawn straight dash polyline somewhere, if you got code related curved line then update your answer also,

Russell suggested link will little helpful to you,

[Drawing Route Between Two Places on GMSMapView in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22550849/drawing-route-between-two-places-on-gmsmapview-in-ios)

You have to do following stuffs,

```
func drawRoute(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {

    //        let directionURL = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?" +
    //            "origin=\(19.0760),\(72.8777)&destination=\(18.520),\(72.9781)&" +
    //        "key=AIzaSyBdzgSm8g6w3daxTQvtlG9pqBxrj3lkaN0"
    //

    var directionURL =  "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=\(coordinate.latitude),\(coordinate.longitude)&destination=\(18.5767),\(73.6881)&key=AIzaSyARoB09HGFjDy3IKfLpZq-ZQd3YwUT-3_E"

    //AIzaSyDxSgGQX6jrn4iq6dyIWAKEOTneZ3Z8PtU

    directionURL += "&mode=" + "walking"

    print("drawRoute")


    Alamofire.request(directionURL).responseJSON
        { response in

            if let JSON = response.result.value {

                let mapResponse: [String: AnyObject] = JSON as! [String : AnyObject]

                let routesArray = (mapResponse["routes"] as? Array) ?? []

                let routes = (routesArray.first as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject>) ?? [:]
                //print("routes : \(routes)")

                //--------Dash line lat-long for starting point ----------\\

                let dictArray = (routes["legs"] as? Array) ?? []
                let dict = (dictArray.first as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject>) ?? [:]
                let steps = (dict["steps"] as? Array) ?? []
                let stepsDict = (steps.first as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject>) ?? [:]

                let startLocation = stepsDict["start_location"]
                let lat = startLocation!["lat"] as! NSNumber
                let lng = startLocation!["lng"] as! NSNumber
                print("lat : \(lat) lng : \(lng)")

                let dotCoordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: CLLocationDegrees(lat), longitude: CLLocationDegrees(lng))

                //--------Route polypoints----------\\


                let overviewPolyline = (routes["overview_polyline"] as? Dictionary<String,AnyObject>) ?? [:]
                let polypoints = (overviewPolyline["points"] as? String) ?? ""
                let line  = polypoints

                self.addPolyLine(encodedString: line, coordinate:coordinate , dotCoordinate:dotCoordinate)
            }
    }

}
```

Now draw route polyline & dash line like following way,

```
func addPolyLine(encodedString: String, coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D ,dotCoordinate : CLLocationCoordinate2D) {

    //--------Dash line to connect starting point---------\\

    let dotPath :GMSMutablePath = GMSMutablePath()
    // add coordinate to your path
    dotPath.add(CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(coordinate.latitude, coordinate.longitude))
    dotPath.add(CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(dotCoordinate.latitude, dotCoordinate.longitude))

    let dottedPolyline  = GMSPolyline(path: dotPath)
    dottedPolyline?.map = self.viewMap
    dottedPolyline?.strokeWidth = 3.0
    let styles: [Any] = [GMSStrokeStyle.solidColor(UIColor.green), GMSStrokeStyle.solidColor(UIColor.clear)]
    let lengths: [Any] = [10, 5]
    dottedPolyline?.spans = GMSStyleSpans(dottedPolyline?.path!, styles as! [GMSStrokeStyle], lengths as! [NSNumber], kGMSLengthRhumb)

    //---------Route Polyline---------\\

    let path = GMSMutablePath(fromEncodedPath: encodedString)
    let polyline = GMSPolyline(path: path)
    polyline?.strokeWidth = 5
    polyline?.strokeColor = .blue
    polyline?.map = self.viewMap

}
```

**See output:**

[image]

Comment: No words to say thank you its **working for me** & sure if i got for curve line i will update to you.

Answer (score 0):

create a `MKPolyLine` like this

```
    var pointsToUse: [CLLocationCoordinate2D] = []
    pointsToUse += [CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(55.4, -3.2)]  // current location
    pointsToUse += [CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(55.6, -3.4)]  // lat lon of starting point

    let polyline = MKPolyline(coordinates: &pointsToUse, count: pointsToUse.count)
    mapView.add(polyline, level: MKOverlayLevel.aboveRoads)
```

and then update the MapView renderer like this

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, rendererFor overlay: MKOverlay) -> MKOverlayRenderer
{
    if (overlay is MKPolyline)
    {
        let pr = MKPolylineRenderer(overlay: overlay)
        pr.strokeColor = UIColor.blue.withAlphaComponent(0.5)
        pr.lineWidth = 2
        pr.lineDashPattern = [10, 10]
        return pr
    }
}
```

Comment: Russell how it is possible to show this on googleMap ? :(  `mapView.add(polyline, level: MKOverlayLevel.aboveRoads)` not accessible to **GMSMapView**

Comment: my mistake - I'm using `MKMapView`.  As far as I can see, it's very similar, but you use `polyline.map = mapView'.    There are some good examples here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22550849/drawing-route-between-two-places-on-gmsmapview-in-ios