# Draw route direction between user's current location to destination in iOS App?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I want to draw route direction from current location to destination using google map direction API.

[image: I have attached an image for example which I want to do.]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22550849/drawing-route-between-two-places-on-gmsmapview-in-ios

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this code **Swift 3.0**-

```
var lat = #your latitude#
var lng = #your longitude#
var location = "your title"
let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: lat, longitude: lng, zoom: 9.0)
var mapView:GMSMapView = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0), size: view.frame.size), camera: camera)
view.addSubview(mapView)

let markerStart = GMSMarker()
markerStart.position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: lat, longitude: lng)
markerStart.title = location
markerStart.snippet = location
markerStart.map = mapView

var latEnd = #your end latitude#
var lngEnd = #your end longitude#

let markerEnd = GMSMarker()
markerEnd.position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: latEnd, longitude: lngEnd)
markerEnd.title = location
markerEnd.snippet = location
markerEnd.map = mapView

let bounds = GMSCoordinateBounds(coordinate: markerStart.position, coordinate: markerEnd.position)
let boundUpdate = GMSCameraUpdate.fit(bounds, withPadding: 40)
mapView.animate(with: boundUpdate)
drawPath(currentLocation: markerStart.position, destinationLoc: markerEnd.position)



func drawPath(currentLocation:CLLocationCoordinate2D,destinationLoc:CLLocationCoordinate2D)
{
    let origin = "\(currentLocation.latitude),\(currentLocation.longitude)"
    let destination = "\(destinationLoc.latitude),\(destinationLoc.longitude)"


    let url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=\(origin)&destination=\(destination)&mode=driving"

    Alamofire.request(url).responseJSON { response in

        let json = JSON(data: response.data!)
        let routes = json["routes"].arrayValue

        for route in routes
        {
            let routeOverviewPolyline = route["overview_polyline"].dictionary
            let points = routeOverviewPolyline?["points"]?.stringValue
            let path = GMSPath.init(fromEncodedPath: points!)
            let polyline = GMSPolyline.init(path: path)
            polyline.strokeColor = UIColor.red
            polyline.strokeWidth = 3
            polyline.map = self.mapView
        }
    }
}
```

**Objective C**

```
    double lat = #your latitude#;
    double lng = #your longitude#;
    double latEnd = #your end latitude#;
    double lngEnd = #your end longitude#;
    NSString *directionsUrlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?&origin=%f,%f&destination=%f,%f&mode=driving", lat, lng, latEnd, lngEnd];
    NSURL *directionsUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:directionsUrlString];


    NSURLSessionDataTask *mapTask = [[NSURLSession sharedSession] dataTaskWithURL:directionsUrl completionHandler:
                                                 ^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error)
                                     {
                                     NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];
                                     if(error)
                                         {
                                         if(completionHandler)
                                             completionHandler(nil);
                                         return;
                                         }

                                     NSArray *routesArray = [json objectForKey:@"routes"];

                                     GMSPolyline *polyline = nil;
                                     if ([routesArray count] > 0)
                                         {
                                         NSDictionary *routeDict = [routesArray objectAtIndex:0];
                                         NSDictionary *routeOverviewPolyline = [routeDict objectForKey:@"overview_polyline"];
                                         NSString *points = [routeOverviewPolyline objectForKey:@"points"];
                                         GMSPath *path = [GMSPath pathFromEncodedPath:points];
                                         polyline = [GMSPolyline polylineWithPath:path];
                                         }

                                     // run completionHandler on main thread
                                     dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                                         if(completionHandler)
                                             completionHandler(polyline);
                                     });
                                     }];
    [mapTask resume];
}
```

Comment: Can u give me the Objective c code for the same. @Abhishek