# I want to draw zigzag polyline using google map

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, google-maps, cocoa-touch

When i am using the below code it is giving me a straight polyline, but i want zigzag according to the route as shown in image i posted.I am using following code.

```
GMSMarker *marker = [[GMSMarker alloc] init];
marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(center.latitude,center.longitude);
marker.title = @"";
marker.snippet = @"";
//marker.map = mapView_;
marker.map = self.mapView;

marker.groundAnchor=CGPointMake(0.5,0.5);
marker.map=_mapView;
GMSMutablePath *path = [GMSMutablePath path];
[path addCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(userLatitude,userLongitude)];
[path addCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(center.latitude,center.longitude)];

GMSPolyline *rectangle = [GMSPolyline polylineWithPath:path];
rectangle.strokeWidth = 2.f;
rectangle.map = _mapView;
self.view=_mapView;

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mVvIV.png
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you might be looking for is to get the directions from Google Directions API and then draw the polylines along that path.
Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20944790/6124074) is what you are looking for.