# Enable direction in Google Maps SDK in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps

When I click on `GMSMarker`, I want to enable direction and map like below image. Its working fine in android.

[image: Like Red Color Box]

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked this [Maps SDK for iOS](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/marker) documentation? You can use the [Google Directions API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/) to request directions, and then use the encoded path returned from the service to draw a [GMSPolyline](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/reference/interface_g_m_s_polyline) using [GMSPath's pathFromEncodedPath:](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/reference/interface_g_m_s_path#a4060269354374332afbb532557c4899e) method.

Here's a related SO thread: [Google Maps iOS SDK, Getting Directions between 2 locations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20905797/google-maps-ios-sdk-getting-directions-between-2-locations). This [blog tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/109888/google-maps-ios-sdk-tutorial) might also help.